# Background image alignment for android devices in unity 3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am developing a unity 3d game for android plotform, what my problem was background image setting, background image is not fit to scene properly for some devices it is ok but for some devices it doesn't.
I used GUItexture property for background image setting. Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i didn't created the texture through coding but using file inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a GUITexture to match your screen size you should Set all pixel inset values to 0 and set the scale to x=1, y=1 and position to 0.5 0.5
on **Transform** : **Position**: (0.5, 0.5, 0) **Rotation**: (0, 0, 0) **Scale**: (1, 1, 1)
on **GUI Texture** : **All** number values set to **0**

Comment: Thats work great thank you for your answer...Sorry am not able to vote up for your answer as i don't have reputation